# Script for simple game however every-time you choose answer, it adds more score points then it should be

Tags: javascript

I am writing a script in Javascript that will basically list questions from an array and then a function will take the questions and then will take the answers from another function to list them and with addEventListener Click will see which option you choose to do something. So far it simply adds score points in a way once you choose the right answer or simply refreshes the questions function when it hits incorrect one. The code is not that short, so I will try to shorten it as possible.

The problem comes when you choose the right answer for second time in a row. It actually gives more than just 1 score point - like several and every time a different number which I am not entirely sure why it does that since following the logic it shouldn't.

The answers are all the same for the moment for testing purposes and never-mind the images - it is a joke project with some of my colleagues :D

Here is what I got at the moment:

```js
   var answerOneDone = 0;
    var answerTwoDone = 0;
    var answerThreeDone = 0;
    var answerFourDone = 0;
    
    var randomNumberBetween0and2 = 0;
    
    var score = 0;
    
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
              // GET RANDOM NUMBER
    function randNum() {
    randomNumberBetween0and2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);   // get random number 0-6
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    
    
                // QUIZZ QUESTIONS WITH IMAGES
    var MyArray = [
    
    {
    "song1": {
         name: "Q elate ",
          name2: " pri ",
          name3: " da vi ",
          name4: " sladko, sladko!",
          image: 'images/1-1.png',
          image2: 'images/1-2.png',
          image3: 'images/1-3.png',
          answered: false, 
      }
    },
    
    {
    "song2": {
         name: "Ooooo ",
          name2: " imash li ",
          image: 'images/2-1.png',
          image2: 'images/2-2.png',
          answered: false,
      }
    },
    
    {
    "song3": {
         name: " minah pokrai ",
          name2: " sveteshe ",
          name3: " sveteshe, a teb te ",
          image: 'images/3-1.png',
          image2: 'images/3-2.png',
          image3: 'images/3-3.png',
          image4: 'images/3-4.png',
          answered: false, 
      }
    },
    
    {
    "song4": {
         name: " li dobre? ",
          name2: " li se? Zashtoto az ",
          name3: " li te? ",
          image: 'images/4-1.png',
          image2: 'images/4-2.png',
          image3: 'images/4-3.png',
          image4: 'images/4-4.png', 
          image5: 'images/4-5.png',
          answered: false, 
      }
    },
    
    ];   
    
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
              // GENERATE ANSWERS WITH IMAGES AND CLICK ON THEM FUNCTION
    
    function answerOne(){
    
    var image1 = "imagesAnswers/image1.png";
    var image2 = "imagesAnswers/image2.png";
    var image3 = "imagesAnswers/image3.png";
    var image4 = "imagesAnswers/image4.png";
    document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image1+'">' + '  Nasko Mentata';
    document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image2+'">' + '  Fiki';
    document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image3+'">' + '  Tita';
    document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image4+'">' + '  Milko Kalaidjiev';
    
    
    document.getElementById("answer1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Wrong!';
    console.log('Wrong!');
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    document.getElementById("answer2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Wrong!';
    console.log('Wrong!');
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    document.getElementById("answer3").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Wrong!';
    console.log('Wrong!');
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    document.getElementById("answer4").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log('Correct!');
    answerOneDone = answerOneDone++;
    score = score+1;
    document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML = '';
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    }
    
    
    function answerTwo(){
    
    var image1 = "imagesAnswers/image1.png";
    var image2 = "imagesAnswers/image2.png";
    var image3 = "imagesAnswers/image3.png";
    var image4 = "imagesAnswers/image4.png";
    document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image1+'">' + '  Nasko Mentata';
    document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image2+'">' + '  Fiki';
    document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image3+'">' + '  Tita';
    document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image4+'">' + '  Milko Kalaidjiev';
    
    
    document.getElementById("answer1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Wrong!';
    console.log('Wrong!');
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    document.getElementById("answer2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Wrong!';
    console.log('Wrong!');
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    document.getElementById("answer3").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Wrong!';
    console.log('Wrong!');
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    document.getElementById("answer4").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log('Correct!');
    answerOneDone = answerOneDone++;
    score = score+1;
    document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML = '';
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    }
    
    
    function answerThree(){
    
    var image1 = "imagesAnswers/image1.png";
    var image2 = "imagesAnswers/image2.png";
    var image3 = "imagesAnswers/image3.png";
    var image4 = "imagesAnswers/image4.png";
    document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image1+'">' + '  Nasko Mentata';
    document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image2+'">' + '  Fiki';
    document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image3+'">' + '  Tita';
    document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image4+'">' + '  Milko Kalaidjiev';
    
    
    document.getElementById("answer1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Wrong!';
    console.log('Wrong!');
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    document.getElementById("answer2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Wrong!';
    console.log('Wrong!');
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    document.getElementById("answer3").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Wrong!';
    console.log('Wrong!');
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    document.getElementById("answer4").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log('Correct!');
    answerOneDone = answerOneDone++;
    score = score+1;
    document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML = '';
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    }
    
    
    function answerFour(){
    
    var image1 = "imagesAnswers/image1.png";
    var image2 = "imagesAnswers/image2.png";
    var image3 = "imagesAnswers/image3.png";
    var image4 = "imagesAnswers/image4.png";
    document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image1+'">' + '  Nasko Mentata';
    document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image2+'">' + '  Fiki';
    document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image3+'">' + '  Tita';
    document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML = '<img src="'+image4+'">' + '  Milko Kalaidjiev';
    
    
    document.getElementById("answer1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Wrong!';
    console.log('Wrong!');
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    document.getElementById("answer2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Wrong!';
    console.log('Wrong!');
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    document.getElementById("answer3").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Wrong!';
    console.log('Wrong!');
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    document.getElementById("answer4").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log('Correct!');
    answerOneDone = answerOneDone++;
    score = score+1;
    document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML = '';
    generateQuestions();             // RESTART THE QUIZZ
    });
    
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    
              // RANDOMLY GENERATE THE QUESTIONS
    
    function generateQuestions(){
    
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = 'Score Points = ' + score;
    
    randNum();
    var q=MyArray[randomNumberBetween0and2];
    
    
    
    if (randomNumberBetween0and2 === 0 && answerOneDone === 0){
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = q.song1.name + '<img src="'+q.song1.image+'">' + '<img src="'+q.song1.image+'">' + '<img src="'+q.song1.image+'">' + q.song1.name2 + '<img src="'+q.song1.image2+'">' + q.song1.name3 + '<img src="'+q.song1.image3+'">' + q.song1.name4;
    answerOne();
    
     } else if (randomNumberBetween0and2 === 1 && answerTwoDone === 0){
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = q.song2.name + '<img src="'+q.song2.image+'">' + '<img src="'+q.song2.image+'">' + q.song2.name2 + '<img src="'+q.song2.image2+'">';
    answerTwo();
     
    } else if (randomNumberBetween0and2 === 2 && answerThreeDone === 0){
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = '<img src="'+q.song3.image+'">' + q.song3.name + '<img src="'+q.song3.image2+'">' + ', ' + '<img src="'+q.song3.image3+'">' + q.song3.name2 + '<img src="'+q.song3.image3+'">' + q.song3.name3 + '<img src="'+q.song3.image4+'">';
    answerThree();
    
     } else if (randomNumberBetween0and2 === 3 && answerFourDone === 0){
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = '<img src="'+q.song4.image+'">' + ', ' + '<img src="'+q.song4.image2+'">' + q.song4.name + '<img src="'+q.song4.image5+'">' + q.song4.name3 + '<img src="'+q.song4.image3+'">' + q.song4.name2 + '<img src="'+q.song4.image4+'">';
    answerFour();
     
    } else if (score >= 4){
    window.alert('You Win!');
    } else {
    window.alert('You Win without score!');
    //generateQuestions();
    }
    
    }
    
    
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
            // RUN THE QUESTIONS
    generateQuestions();
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Shushan</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <p id="score"></p>
    <p id="question"></p>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    <p id="answer1"></p>
    <p id="answer2"></p>
    <p id="answer3"></p>
    <p id="answer4"></p>
    </br>
    </br>
    <p id="test"></p>
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

The idea with the RANDOMLY GENERATE THE QUESTIONS part is to choose random question every-time and added the answerOneDone === 0 part to check if this question was used before, otherwise will try to restart that function and check again with another number.

I really appreciate your help on that one since I am missing something in there definitely. Thank you!

Comment: There's not much point in trying to fix your code as long as you are in such massive violation of the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: I am still novice here when it comes to Javascript, though I though that this might have something do to with it. Not sure if using the same function that many times throughout the code is the cause of the issues I am having with it and wanted to check if there is any way to avoid that?

Comment: The main issue is that you're calling `addEventListener()` over and over again on the answer elements and never calling `removeEventListener()`, which means those old listeners are being fired right along side the new ones. You'll need to re-organize your code pretty dramatically in order to fix it.

Comment: Thank you! I though that this might be it and tried once adding removeEventListener() at the end of every answer (or maybe just the correct one out of the 4 in there), however nothing happened. Will try adding it again to all the options to see if that is what is causing the trouble and will update you :)

Comment: That definitely fixed it (applying removeEventListener() to all the options and not just the winning one. Thank you for that big time! :) 

 The issue now I have is that when I click on some of the answers (only the same one) and eventually click on another answer, it add as many score points as the times I have clicked previously (all the same time) :D I assume I might be missing something else, but will give it some time to think about it first. Really thank you for the help!

Comment: I am beginning to think that this quiz project is homework. I have seen about 6 questions that are all similar with every different ways of writing their code. But the end result  of the quiz is amazingly similar.